# How can I get the first result from a JSON using JSONPATH. Confused

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am unsure of what to do. I've tried "$..name" which gives me all the names in the json, then I tried "$..name[0]" which should give me the first result, but didn't. What should I do? I tried this on [json path tester](https://jsonpath.com/).

```
JSON I'm using: https://pastebin.com/zuarCkjK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
$..[0].name
```

If it works right, the output should be

```
[
  "test1"
]
```